# Profiling performance-sensitive code paths

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization

I have a function that receives 2 arguments and 1 additional, optional argument. The function must return `true` if the first argument is bigger than the second one, `false` if not, except if the third argument is `true` (the third argument can be only true or false, false by default), in which case the function should return true if the first argument is either bigger or equal (strict comparison) to the second argument.

The function isn't guaranteed to receive arguments of the same type, or even arguments that make any sense (the function could be called with `null, undefined`). Anyways, the function must obey javascript behavior to compare the received arguments.

I have two functions, and I believe the second one should be faster, but neither my own benchmarks nor [jsperf results](http://jsperf.com/gthelper-if-vs-gthelper-switch) say so. In fact, the first function is ~30-35%  faster, which is quite a lot.

How can I track down the slow code paths inside each function? How can I know why the second function is slower?

This is my benchmark:

```
var microtime = require('microtime');

/* Helper functions */

function maybeBool() {
    if(Math.round(Math.random() * 1)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function maybeNullUndef() {
    if(Math.round(Math.random() * 1)) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return undefined;
    }
}

function randomString() {
    return Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0, 5);
}

function randomDate() {
    var y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
    return new Date(y);
}

function something() {
    var x = Math.round(Math.random()*3);

    switch(x) {
        case 0:
            return maybeBool();
            break;

        case 1:
            return maybeNullUndef();
            break;

        case 2:
            return randomString();
            break;

        case 3:
            return randomDate();
            break;
    }
}

var things_to_compare = [];

for(i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
    var a = something();
    var b = something();
    things_to_compare.push([a, b]);
}

/* First function */

function gtHelper(prop1, prop2, equal) {

    // 'falsy' and Boolean handling
    if (!prop1 || !prop2 || prop1 === true || prop2 === true) {
    if ((prop1 === true || prop1 === false) && (prop2 === true || prop2 === false)) {
        if (equal) {
        return prop1 === prop2;
        } else {
        if (prop1) {
            return !prop2;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        }
    }

    if (prop1 === undefined || prop1 === null || prop1 === false || prop2 === true) {
        return !!equal || false;
    }
    if (prop2 === undefined || prop2 === null || prop1 === true || prop2 === false) {
        return true;
    }

    if (prop1 > prop2) {
        return true;
    }

    if (prop1 < prop2) {
        return false;
    }

    // not lt and and not gt so equality assumed-- this ordering of tests is date compatible
    return equal;
    }

    if (prop1 > prop2) {
    return true;
    }

    if (prop1 < prop2) {
    return false;
    }

    // not lt and and not gt so equality assumed-- this ordering of tests is date compatible
    return equal;
}


/* Second function */

function gtHelper2 (prop1, prop2, equal) {

    equal = !!equal;

    //If 'prop1' is any of those, the result will be always 'false',
    //unless 'equal' is true.
    switch (prop1) {
            case "":
            case null:
            case false:
            case undefined:
                    return (prop1 === prop2 && equal);
    }

    //If 'prop2' is any of those, the result will be always 'true'
    switch (prop2) {
            case "":
            case null:
            case false:
            case undefined:
                    return true;
    }

    if (prop1 > prop2 || (prop1 === prop2 && equal)) {
            return true;
    } else if (prop1 < prop2) {
            return false;
    } else {
            return equal;
    }
}

/* Benchmark */

var res1 = 0;
for(n = 0; n < 30; n++) {
var now = microtime.now();
    for(i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
        gtHelper(things_to_compare[i][0], things_to_compare[i][1]);
    }
var now1 = microtime.now();

res1 += now1 - now;
}



var res2 = 0;
for(n = 0; n < 30; n++) {
var now = microtime.now();
    for(i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
        gtHelper2(things_to_compare[i][0], things_to_compare[i][1]);
    }
var now1 = microtime.now();

res2 += now1 - now;
}

console.log("gtHelper:", res1/30);
console.log("gtHelper2:", res2/30);
```

Edit:

I have been further working on the second function, I achieved make it a little bit faster, but it keep lagging behind the first function.

This is how it looks now:

```
function gtHelper2 (prop1, prop2, equal) {

    //If 'prop1' is any of those, the result will be always 'false',
    //unless 'equal' is true.
    if (!prop1) {
        return (prop1 === prop2 && !!equal);
    }

    //If 'prop2' is any of those, the result will be always 'true'
    if (!prop2) {
        return true;
    }

    if (prop1 > prop2) {
        return true;
    } else if (prop1 < prop2) {
        return false;
    } else if (prop1 === prop2 && !!equal) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return !!equal;
    }
}
```

Comment: just add more timer calls in there, collect them, and logs them at the end (only run each one once, not a bunch like for a benchmark...)

Comment: @dandavis Yes, but still, the second function is composed by 2 switches and 2 if's. It should be faster, and I can't understand why is it slower.

Answer (score 0):

Your two functions do not return the same thing.

```
gtHelper(true, 'string')         // true
gtHelper2(true, 'string')        // false

gtHelper('string', new Date())  // undefined
gtHelper2('string', new Date()) // false

gtHelper(new Date(), 'string')  // undefined
gtHelper2(new Date(), 'string') // false
```

If you can get these functions behaving the same, I am sure you will see more meaningful results.

You should be aware that, in the browser at least, you should not expect `switch` to perform the same on all platforms. You should read the [ECMA spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.11) on `switch` to see why optimising this should be so difficult. I know that Firefox did spend a good deal of time on making their `switch` implementation perform well. I've heard nothing about anything similar on V8.